# Sharepoint anonymous user search results

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010

We have two zones - Default is Claims based and Custom is NTLM - this one is used for crawling.

My issue is that when I search under anonymous user - the protected content is returned, even though when I try to click the link - it gives me permission error (which is good).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/82af0cf2-ca5b-4009-87ff-c6cf02414f43/) may solve your problem.

It defines the problem that, old crawl data is still on. That a new crawl will solve it.
If it does not, may be you should check your data's permissions that no anonymous user has view permission on it.

And, although it is not related to your question about sharepoint 2010, [this](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/max/archive/2008/02/20/sharepoint-search-and-anonymous-users.aspx) can help MOSS 2007 users if needed.

Comment: The anonymous does not have access - since when I click the link - I get access denied; yes, we did multiple recrawls